# Trying combination logic in Lists in C#

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2012

I am using Lists in C#. I have a class this way:

```
UserManager {
  User User;
  Other Variables;
}
```

And the `User` class has some variables like:

```
User {
  String Username, Password;
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is, having a list of `UserManager`s and finding it by `Username` and that worked this way:

```
UserManager U = UM.Find(
  item => item.Username == Username
);
```

But I would like to employ a check for both `Username` and `Password` combination. I am new to C# and confused on how to implement. Tried this but no luck:

```
// Attempt #1
UserManager U = UM.Find(
  item => item.Username == Username && item => item.Password == Password
);

// Attempt #2
UserManager U = UM.Find(
  item => item.Username == Username, item => item.Password == Password
);

// Attempt #3
UserManager U = UM.Find(
  item => item.Username == Username, item.Password == Password
);
```

BTW, `Username` and `Password` are `String`s taken from the user through `Console.ReadLine()`. Please help me out in proceeding further...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not repeat the input parameter item

```
UserManager U = UM.Find(
  item => item.Username == Username && item.Password == Password
);
```

Comment: Can you explain the structure? What's that `item` and how it is supposed to be used?

Comment: Well, you should read something about lambda expression. It is really a broad argument. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596516109-03-09.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do

```
UserManager U = UM.Find(
item => item.Username == Username && item.Password == Password
);
```

Failing that you could do

```
UserManager U = UM.Where(
item => item.Username == Username && item.Password == Password
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
if(Users.Any(user => user.UserName.Equals(UserName) &&
                                 user.Password.Equals(Password)) {

     var matchedUser = Users.Where(user => user.UserName.Equals(UserName) &&
                                 user.Password.Equals(Password));

     //....
    }
```